# ¿Cómo realizo vuelvo habilitar un checkbox despues de haberlo bloqueado con otro check box en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Buenas!

Tengo este ejemplo que recogí de w3schools.com

### pero me muestran como bloquearlo, pero no desbloquearlo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<p>HACER CLICK PARA DESHABILITAR.</p>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Supongo que se podría hacer con una operación contraria a la de dar click que no conozco... o una misma opción con diferente funcion en el script(cosa que experimente pero no funciona)

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
      document.getElementById("chk1").onclick = function(){
       if (document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled){
        document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = false
       }else{
        document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true
       }
      }
```

```html
     Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
    
     <p>HACER CLICK PARA DESHABILITAR.</p>
    
     <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">Deshabilitar</button>
```

Evaluar en el evento click si esta deshabilitado para volver a habilitarlo y viceversa :D

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: MUUUUUUCHAS gracias por ayudar a este humilde novato :D

Comment: Gracias a ti :D. ¡Éxitos!

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() 
{
   var control = document.getElementById("myCheck");

   if(control.checked)
   {
      control.checked= false;
   }
    else
   {
      control.checked= true;
   }
}
```

Eso debería funcionar, sin embargo te recomiendo que utilices jquery

```
function myFunction() 
    {
       var control = $("#myCheck");

       if(control.checked)
       {
          $("#myCheck").prop("checked", false);
       }
        else
       {
           $("#myCheck").prop("checked", false);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Funciona pero no lo bloquea y desbloquea el otro check, solo lo chequa y deschequa. El tuyo hace esto: https://jsfiddle.net/5qo4v1vo/  ----- Pero el que necesito deberia hacer esto: https://jsfiddle.net/tg1qo9hh/ ---- De todas manera tu aporte tambien es necesario para parte de lo que tengo que hacer en mi proyecto muchas gracias :D

Comment: si, luego me di cuenta de que buscabas desbloquear y bloquear, no checkear y unckeckear

Comment: Entendí mal la pregunta

Comment: De igual manera Muchas Gracias este pedacito de codigo tambien me sirve

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<p>HACER CLICK PARA DESHABILITAR.</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="validacion" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = document.getElementById("validacion").checked;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```